# Derivative of a quadratic cost function with respect to a vector

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, matrix-calculus, quadratic-forms, scalar-fields

I am new to matrix calculus and have a question regarding finding the derivative of the cost function defined below with respect to $\theta$, which is actually the exponential term of a multinomial distribution.

$$Q = (x-H\theta)^T C^{-1} (x-H\theta)\\ = (x^T -\theta^TH^T) C^{-1} (x-H\theta) \\ = x^T C^{-1} x - x^T C^{-1} H \theta - \theta^T H^T C^{-1} x + \theta^T H^T C^{-1} H \theta$$

How do I get the derivative of the 3rd term since $\theta$ is transposed. The 4th term also since there are 2 $\theta$'s, transposed and not. Help. Thanks.

Comment: Going back to the definitions helps, as always... So, the goal is to find some linear function $L_\theta$ such that $Q(\theta+\tau)=Q(\theta)+L_\theta(\tau)+o(\tau)$ when $\tau\to0$, right? Then this $L_\theta$ is the differential of $Q$ at $\theta$, as such there exists some $u_\theta$ such that $L_\theta(\tau)=u_\theta^T\tau$ for every $\tau$ and it is customary to identify the differential with the vector $u_\theta$. Any idea to identify $u_\theta$ in the present case? Writing down $L_\theta(\tau)$ should be direct, then there is a small trick to convert it to the form $u_\theta^T\tau$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than expanding the expression immediately, I find it simpler to define new variables (to reduce "clutter" in the function), differentiate, then substitute the original variables in the final steps.

Let
$$\eqalign{
 B &= C^{-1} \cr
 y &= H\theta-x \cr
}$$
Write the function in terms of these variables and take the differential
$$\eqalign{
 Q &= y^TBy \cr
dQ &= dy^TBy + y^TB\,dy \cr
   &= y^T(B^T + B)\,dy \cr
   &= y^T(B^T + B)H\,d\theta \cr
}$$
Since $dQ=(\frac{\partial Q}{\partial\theta}:d\theta),\,$ the gradient must be
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial Q}{\partial\theta} &= y^T(B^T + B)H \cr
  &= (H\theta-x)^T(C^{-T} + C^{-1})\,H \cr
}$$

Comment: Great tip on defining new variables.

Comment: How did you make the simplification from $d^{T} B y + y^{T}Bdy$ to the following line?

Comment: @MortenNissov For a real matrix $(A)$ and real vectors $(x,y)\,$ one has the following identity $$x^TA^Ty \;=\; y^TAx$$ Although $dy$ is a differential, it obeys all of the rules of matrix algebra.

Comment: Is there a derivation or a source documenting this? Because it just looks like one sides been transposed.

And I guess, in general, you can't just transpose a matrix product without changing the result; at least as far as the order of the entries is concerned? Or am I mistaken?

Edit: Just realized, since the matrix product results in a scalar quantity you actually can just transpose it without effecting the result. So rearranging via transpose here is free i suppose

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve it via the product rule with the property I saw [here](http://www4.ncsu.edu/~pfackler/MatCalc.pdf) at page 4 which basically states that $ D[ f(x)^Tg(x)] = g(x)^Tf^{'}(x) + f(x)^Tg^{'}(x)$. I have verified my answer with the solution posted by lynn.

Answer (score 0):

Write

$$\begin{array}{rl} Q (x,\theta) &= (x - H \theta)^T C^{-1} (x - H \theta)\\ &= \begin{bmatrix} x\\ \theta\end{bmatrix}^T \begin{bmatrix} I\\ -H^T\end{bmatrix} C^{-1} \begin{bmatrix} I\\ -H^T\end{bmatrix}^T \begin{bmatrix} x\\ \theta\end{bmatrix}\\ &= \begin{bmatrix} x\\ \theta\end{bmatrix}^T \begin{bmatrix} C^{-1} & - C^{-1} H\\ -H^T C^{-1} & H^T C^{-1} H\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x\\ \theta\end{bmatrix}\end{array}$$

Since the derivative of $y^T A y$ with respect to $y$ is $(A + A^T) y$, the derivative of $Q$ with respect to $(x,\theta)$, assuming that $C^{-1}$ is symmetric, is the following

$$2 \begin{bmatrix} C^{-1} & - C^{-1} H\\ -H^T C^{-1} & H^T C^{-1} H\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x\\ \theta\end{bmatrix}$$

Thus, the derivative of $Q$ with respect to $\theta$ alone is

$$2 H^T C^{-1} (H \theta - x)$$